# Replace Long Annotations in Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, annotations, springdoc

I am developing Spring Boot using Kotlin. Now I want to create API docs, however their Annotations are clumsy and wordy.

Current:

```
@ApiResponses(
    ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Result depending on the role of the user", content = [Content(schema = Schema(oneOf = [AdminResponse::class, UserResponse::class]))])
)
fun get(authentication: Authentication): Any {
[...]
}
```

What I want it looks like:

```
@Api(
    Response(200, "Result depending on the role of the user", [AdminResponse::class, UserResponse::class])
)
fun get(authentication: Authentication): Any {
[...]
}
```

Can I use something to archieve this? Some ideas are Preprocessing and Typealiases.

Answer (score 2):

The swagger annotations are in place for many years, stable and garantee a great result in order to be compliant to OpenAPI 3 specification.

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations

This is said, you can create your own annotations and reinvent the wheel...